# C Program Outputting an Error when I divide two variables

Tags: c, math

I am trying to make a program to output the height of a rectangle by getting user to input two numbers (area and width) then dividing the two variables (area and width) to get the result of height. When running this program I get 0.0000 as the result.

I think it might be something to do with the conversion specifiers for one of my scanf or printf lines.

I am just learning C so having trouble working out what the issue is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* initilize variables (area, width and height) */
    float area, width, height;
    /* assign variables */
    area = 0.0;
    width = 0.0;
    height = 0.0;
    /* Gather user input */
    printf("Enter the area in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &area);
    printf("Enter the width in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &width);
    /* Height of a rectangle = area/width */
    height = area/width;
    /* Print result */
    printf("The height of the rectangle is: %f", &height);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your last `printf` is wrong. You aren't supposed to pass the address of `height` (so remove the `&`).

Comment: I really suggest that you learn how to use the *debugger.* The you would see quickly that `height` gets the *correct* value. So the problem is unrelated to "dividing two variables" and only your print statement is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR How to use it, i also want to learn it, but i do not know the best source.

Comment: Great thank you. I have been stuck on this for a few hours and couldn't work out where I went wrong.

Comment: @JakeRitter Hours??

Comment: @JakeRitter  i highly Recommend K.N king C Programming A Modern Approach 2nd Edition. It will help you a lot.

Comment: you said `initilize variables` in the comment but then after that only declares the variables without intializing at all. And *the width in **square metres***? What???

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in line

```
    printf("The height of the rectangle is: %f", &height)
```

It should be `height` instead of `&height`.

Change it to

```
    printf("The height of the rectangle is: %f", height)
```

And You are good to go.

I have tested it now and it is good.

```
Enter the area in square metres
12
Enter the width in square metres
3
The height of the rectangle is: 4.000000
```

And as pointed out by [MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) in the comment to the question, you should learn to use Debugger Then you would see quickly that `height` gets the correct value. So the problem is unrelated to "dividing two variables" and only your print statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, all your code is correct except for the final `printf()` line.

Other responses suggest a debugger. If you're unfamiliar with debuggers the best way you can get started is with an online debugger such as [onlinegdb](http://www.onlinegdb.com/).

When the debugger hits the breakpoint, you will see that your values for `area`, `width` and `height` in the right hand pane of "local variables" are spot on.

And so therefore you can deduce that the problem could only be at the final line where you put the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

That was just a tiny mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* initilize variables (area, width and height) */
    float area, width, height;
    /* assign variables */
    area = 0.0;
    width = 0.0;
    height = 0.0;
    /* Gather user input */
    printf("Enter the area in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &area);
    printf("Enter the width in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &width);
    /* Height of a rectangle = area/width */
    height = area / width;
    /* Print result */
    printf("The height of the rectangle is: %f", height);

    return 0;
}
```

Manual test

```
Enter the area in square metres
25
Enter the width in square metres
5
The height of the rectangle is: 5.000000
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a typo problem, you are printing the address of the height variable (`&height`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* initilize variables (area, width and height) */
    float area, width, height;
    /* assign variables */
    area = 0.0;
    width = 0.0;
    height = 0.0;
    /* Gather user input */
    printf("Enter the area in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &area);
    printf("Enter the width in square metres\n");
    scanf("%f", &width);
    /* Height of a rectangle = area/width */
    height = area/width;
    /* I have just changed &height to height  */
     printf("The height of the rectangle is: %f", height);

    return 0;
}
```